# Python Removing Words from list even if they match criteria

Tags: python-3.x

I just got started programming in python two days ago, and i am trying to create a simple hangman game where the computer guesses the word using a .txt file which contains a lot of English words (about 69.9k) and i am basically asking the user some questions and removing unnecessary words.
However along the line python would remove the words even though they match the criteria and i have even tried using print on the listname.pop() function but the missing words dont show up in there.

I have Already Tried checking if i am properly adding the words to the word list and it seems to be correct since i have directly printed from the list, the main file doesnt have much more than just print stuff and input stuff so there should not be any problem there.

This is the basic code:

```
    from ReadFile import ReadFile

    w_list = ReadFile()
    n_list = []


    def RemoveExtraByRange(range_w):

        for x, words in enumerate(w_list):

            if len(words) != int(range_w):
                w_list.pop(x)
            else:
                n_list.append(w_list[x])


    def RemoveExtraByFLetter(f_letter):
        w_list.clear()

        for x, words in enumerate(n_list):

            if not words.startswith(f_letter):
                n_list.pop(x)
            else:
                w_list.append(n_list[x])


    def RemoveExtraByLLetter(l_letter):
        n_list.clear()

        for x, words in enumerate(w_list):
            if not words.endswith(l_letter):
                w_list.pop(x)
            else:
                n_list.append(words)

        w_list.clear()
```

Edit: Converted Lists to Sets(this doesnt matter since each word is unique). also changed n list to only contain unnecessary word, in the start of each function i clear the n_list. also instead of pop i use w_list -= n_list out of the loop. this fixed it for me.

Comment: Welcome Mohsin. The txt file you mention contains just words and nothing else? Could you please post a small sample of it?

Comment: You are, in multiple places, modifying a list in the middle of looping over it, which can cause problems.

Comment: yes just words. one word on each line. here is the list: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/wordlist

Comment: @ScottHunter So what would be the easier way out? just put the index of words that i want to remove and remove them later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you use modify list in loop.
If you go through enumerated list and pop index you change the list.
Let's make it on an example:

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in range(3):
    a.pop(i)
```

then `a == [2,4]`

That I would do, would be operate on sets first (because I guess that list of words is unique)

Then in loop just create a set with words that doesn't fulfil the needs and change the original set.

Something like:

```py
w_list = set()
n_list = set()

...

for word in w_list:
    if len(words) == int(range_w):
        n_list.add(word)
w_list -= n_list
```

Comment: oh ok i dont know why i never though of that. using pop will change the index which in turn would give me undesired results. if i understand you correctly, i basically have to store the unwanted words in a list during the loop and then after the loop just remove those words from the original list. thanks i will try that and mark this as correct if it works

Comment: hmm so i just tried doing it again, i have two problems. i cant do w_list -= n_list. i tried this instead after the loop ends:   ```for x in n_list:
        w_list.pop(x)```. however just as i though this would give me indexoutofrange exeception errors. also i would like to mention that i have already tried doing listname.remove() but i still got the same issues (though i did that in the loop). the thing is if it is a matter of index changing it should not effect remove() since it does not use the index but rather searches for the given object.

Comment: "i cant do `w_list -= n_list`" -- why not?  If it failed, what was the error message?  If it produced the wrong result, how was it wrong?

Comment: @ScottHunter i got a TypeError Exception.
```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'list' and 'list'```

Comment: you can't do add and subtraction operations on list. That's why you should change it to sets. Then it should be ok.

Comment: n_list you can declare at the beginning as a set `n_list = set()` and w_list you can change later to set `w_list = set(w_list)` I would change name of the variables though

Comment: yep thanks i got it to work. i will mark this as the correct answer and also post the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is to gather the indices of what you want to remove, then do so in reverse order:

```
def RemoveExtraByRange(range_w):
    to_go = []
    for x, words in enumerate(w_list):
        if len(words) != int(range_w):
            to_go.append( x )
        else:
            n_list.append(words)
    to_go.reverse()
    for x in to_go:
        w_list.pop(x)
```